# Links and simple form in single line

Tags: html, css, forms

I want links and simple form in single line

```
<a href="new.php">link1</a>
<a href="view.php">link2</a>
<a href="index.html">link3</a>

<form method="POST" asp-area="" asp-page="/PagesWithTables/ShowProduktyTable">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>       
    <input asp-for="Input.Search" value="@Model.search"/>
</form>
```

so it looks like this

```
link1 link2 link3   search [______]
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: using <p></p> on every element and doing inline in css

Answer (score 0):

so it was necessary? the `main` container is now 100% width, but you can reduce the distance, and then the objects will be closer to each other.

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="links">
  <a href="new.php">link1</a>
  <a href="view.php">link2</a>
  <a href="index.html">link3</a>
 </div>

  <form method="POST" asp-area="" asp-page="/PagesWithTables/ShowProduktyTable">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>       
      <input asp-for="Input.Search" value="@Model.search"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to wrap all those elements in a flex div:

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="new.php">link1</a>
<a href="view.php">link2</a>
<a href="index.html">link3</a>

<form class="my-form" method="POST" asp-area="" asp-page="/PagesWithTables/ShowProduktyTable">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>       
    <input asp-for="Input.Search" value="@Model.search"/>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: flex
}

.menu a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

If you want to right-align the search:

```
.my-form {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```